# Javascript Syntax Confussion

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

```
// The keys and notes variables store the piano keys
const keys = ['c-key', 'd-key', 'e-key', 'f-key', 'g-key', 'a-key', 'b-key', 
'high-c-key', 'c-sharp-key', 'd-sharp-key', 'f-sharp-key', 'g-sharp-key', 'a- 
sharp-key'];
const notes = [];
keys.forEach(function(key){
notes.push(document.getElementById(key));
})

// Write named functions that change the color of the keys below
const keyPlay = function(event){
event.target.style.backgroundColor = "#ababab"; 
}
const keyReturn = function(event){
event.target.style.backgroundColor = ""; 
}
// Write a named function with event handler properties
function eventAssignment(note){
note.onmousedown = keyPlay;
note.onmouseup = function(){
    keyReturn(event);
}
}

// Write a loop that runs the array elements through the function
notes.forEach(eventAssignment);
```

LINE-17 and LINE-18 serve similar purposes by triggering event handlers well the instructor tells me not to use this syntax at LINE-17 even though it works fine. he sort of mentions something which completely hops over my mind "we can't define `note.onmousedown` to the `keyPlay` function as it would just redefine the function (i have no idea which function is he referring to as being redefined)"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't "trigger" event handlers, it "assigns" event handlers. Among those two, `note.onmousedown = keyPlay;` is the right way to go about this. But maybe the instructor was referring to using `addEventListener` instead, which allows to bind multiple handlers to the same event (`.onmousedown = ...` would overwrite any previous handler defined that way).

Comment: he wasn't referring to addEventListener that for sure i can tell you. i am expecting a comparison btw line 17 and line 18

Comment: If that is the case, you will have to ask your instructor for clarification. Like Felix said, among those two, `note.onmousedown = keyPlay;` is the right way to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

First line will call keyPlay directly on mouse down, meanwhile the second one will create a function that then will call keyReturn. The second line is actually wrong as event is undefined (you have to declare it in function's input). I prefer the first line as it allows you to keep code cleaner.

Comment: [`event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event) isn't `undefined` in the second line.